# Is there a code pattern for mapping a CSV with random column order to defined properties?

Tags: c#, csv, design-patterns

I have a CSV that is delivered to my application from various sources. The CSV will **always** have the same number columns and the header values for the columns will **always** be the same.

However, the columns may not always be in the same order.

**Day 1 CSV may look like this**

```
ID,FirstName,LastName,Email
1,Johh,Lennon,jlennon@applerecords.com
2,Paul,McCartney,macca@applerecords.com
```

**Day 2 CSV may look like this**

```
Email,FirstName,ID,LastName
resident1@friarpark.com,George,3,Harrison
ringo@allstarrband.com,Ringo,4,Starr
```

I want to read in the header row for each file and have a simple mechanism for associating each "column" of data with the associated property I have defined in my class.

I know I can use selection statements to figure it out, but that seems like a "bad" way to handle it.

Is there a simple way to map "columns" to properties using a dictionary or class at runtime?

Comment: reflection.  create a dictionary of the field name and a func of how to handle the that field.

Comment: Use a [Dictionary<string, int>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx) to map column name to column position.

Comment: Idea is to read first line and determined 0 based index for each header column. `Dictionary<string, int>` as said by @mbeckish

Comment: Although a valid question, design pattern tends to communicate something other than what you are looking for. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern ... Algorithm might be a better word.

Comment: @Jeremy Cook changed, thanks.

Comment: @mbeckish I can map using a Dictionary, but then I still need to use a switch statement on the results of the string to map it back to a property.

Comment: @JeffJohnson - Yes, but 1) Most of your post seems to suggest your problem is with the order of columns changing.  The dictionary addresses that., and 2) Your example has a very small number of fields.  Just hard-code the assignment of 4 properties based on the column heading string.

Comment: @mbeckish Yes, I see it now. If you want to add an answer, I'll mark it as correct, otherwise, I'll add in a code example to my question later. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a Dictionary to map column heading text to column position.
Hard-code mapping of column heading text to object property.

Example:

```
// Parse first line of text to add column heading strings and positions to your dictionary
...

// Parse data row into an array, indexed by column position
...

// Assign data to object properties
x.ID = row[myDictionary["ID"]];
x.FirstName = row[myDictionary["FirstName"]];
...
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, working it into my code now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You dont need a design pattern for this purpose.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

I have used this Reader, while it is pretty good, it has a functionality as `row["firstname"]` or `row["id"]` which you can parse and create your objects.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, however, I'm not looking for a third party IO framework for handling the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I have parsed both CSV files using [`Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser.aspx). I have populated `DataTable` after parsing both csv files:

```
DataTable dt;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     dt = new DataTable();
     ParseCSVFile("day1.csv");
     ParseCSVFile("day2.csv");
     dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;            
}

private void ParseCSVFile(string sFileName)
{
    var dIndex = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    using (TextFieldParser csvReader = new TextFieldParser(sFileName))
    {                
        csvReader.Delimiters = new string[] { "," };
        var colFields = csvReader.ReadFields();

        for (int i = 0; i < colFields.Length; i++)
        {
            string sColField = colFields[i];

            if (sColField != string.Empty)
            {
                dIndex.Add(sColField, i);

                if (!dt.Columns.Contains(sColField))
                   dt.Columns.Add(sColField);
            }
        }
        while (!csvReader.EndOfData)
        {
             string[] fieldData = csvReader.ReadFields();

             if (fieldData.Length > 0)
             {
                 DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                 foreach (var kvp in dIndex)
                 {
                     int iVal = kvp.Value;

                     if (iVal < fieldData.Length)
                         dr[kvp.Key] = fieldData[iVal];
                 }

                 dt.Rows.Add(dr);
              }                  

          }
      }
  }
```

`day1.csv` and `day2.csv` as mentioned in the question.

Here is how output `dataGridView1` look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple generic method that will take a CSV file (broken into string[]) and create from it a list of objects.  The assumption is that the object properties will have the same name as the headers.  If this is not the case you might look into the DataMemberAttribute property and modify accordingly.

```
private static List<T> ProcessCSVFile<T>(string[] lines)  
{  

List<T> list = new List<T>();  
Type type = typeof(T);  
string[] headerArray = lines[0].Split(new char[] { ',' });  

PropertyInfo[] properties = new PropertyInfo[headerArray.Length];  
for (int prop = 0; prop < properties.Length; prop++)  
{  
    properties[prop] = type.GetProperty(headerArray[prop]);  
}  
for (int count = 1; count < lines.Length; count++)  
{  
    string[] valueArray = lines[count].Split(new char[] { ',' });
    T t = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    list.Add(t);

    for (int value = 0; value < valueArray.Length; value++)
    {
        properties[value].SetValue(t, valueArray[value], null);
    }
}  
return list;  
}
```

Now, in order to use it just pass your file formatted as an array of strings.  Let's say the class you want to read into looks like this:

```
class Music  
{  
    public string ID { get; set; }  
    public string FirstName { get; set; }  
    public string LastName { get; set; }  
    public string Email { get; set; }  
}
```

So you can call this:

```
List<Music> newlist = ProcessCSVFile<Music>(list.ToArray());
```

...and everything gets done with one call.