# Read specific columns and there values from .CSV file and store it in a hashtable

Tags: c#, csv, hashtable

I want to read specific columns from my .csv file and store the values into a hashtable. The csv file contains total of 9 columns of which I want to read 4 columns and their values (Columns names are like PeopleId, HashValue, SecurityToken, and Date).

I have tried below code but while reading the values I have some concerns.

```
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable(); 
using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(csv_file_path))
{
    parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
    parser.SetDelimiters(",");
    while (!parser.EndOfData)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
            ht.Add(fields[0],fields[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}

foreach (string key in ht.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} : {1}", key, ht[key]));
}
```

I need help how to specify the column name and get only those values in my hashtable.

Comment: Anand you have to try something before you post a question. If you're getting stuck somewhere in the code, post it and someone will help you out. You can't get someone else to do your work.

Comment: Don't use Hashtable, use `Dictionary<string, string>` instead. Or StringDictionary.

Comment: I want the values in format like <Column Name>, <Column Value> (E.G (PeopleID,1) (PeopleID,2),(HashValue,433)(HashValue,867) so was using the Hashtable so that i can get the values in Key Value pair

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a code pattern for mapping a CSV with random column order to defined properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24293646/is-there-a-code-pattern-for-mapping-a-csv-with-random-column-order-to-defined-pr)